# jackson throws IllegalAccessError even with the same versions

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I'm developing a software with jackson, but totally get stuck... When I run the  spring-boot program with `java -jar <MY_APPLICATION>.jar` command, I got the following error:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule.<init>(JavaTimeModule.java:159)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:78)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:719)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:572)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:554)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.jacksonObjectMapper(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2434a0bb.CGLIB$jacksonObjectMapper$0(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2434a0bb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d685921f.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2434a0bb.jacksonObjectMapper(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 85 more
```

There are more error messages above the error, but I think the important message is `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)`, which I know it cannot happen generally.

I confirmed that the jackson modules are in the same version(2.6.5 which comes from spring-boot's dependency), and codehaus's  jackson is not included:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincluces=com.fasterxml.jackson.core | grep -v omitted

...

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ patriot-fdc-web ---
[INFO] <MY_GROUP>:<MY_APPLICATION_A>:war:0.3.9-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- <MY_GROUP>:<MY_APPLICATION_B>:jar:0.3.9-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.5:compile (version managed from 2.4.2)
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.5:compile (version managed from 2.6.0)
```

Can anybody encounter such a problem? Anyone can suggest any solution or possibility for the error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the cause.

The dependency included `calcite-avartica` artifact, and it has a shaded jackson in it with version 2.1.1. That's why I cannot find the dependency by `mvn dependency:tree`. I found it through debugging remotely by seeing where `StdSerializer` came from.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-1110

Avartica 1.9.0 or later might not bother us. I just excluded `calcite-core` and `calcite-avartica` and finally it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue in sbt, the fix was also to remove `calcita-core` and `calcite-avatica` like so

```
ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.calcite", name = "calcite-core"),
ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.calcite", name = "calcite-avatica")
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue, and it was due to transitive dependency of `jackson-datatype-jsr310` with lower version coming along with `jackson-databind`. Got the issue resolved by adding the exclude statement from the first level dependency in `build.gradle`.

```
compile (<dependency>){
exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype", module: "jackson-datatype-jsr310"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are using Maven, just identify which dependency is adding this dependency of Jackson with jsr310. To do this,

1. Open pom in Eclispe and select tab dependency hierarchy and search jsr310
2. Identify the name of dependency by which it is being added
3. Add below exclusion into pom.xml

   <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   </exclusions>